# why web service is called asynchronously? What is the reason behind it?

Tags: web-services

Why web service is called asynchronously? What is the reason behind it?

Comment: HTTP is a stateless protocol.

Comment: 8 questions, 7 answers, none accepted. You won't be getting answers in your questions in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

"Asynchronous" means "not at the same time as other things". The only other "things" are the normal page loads, and these requests happen independently, hence they are "asynchronous".